# How to SaveAs with OneDrive while offline?

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive, offline, save-as

I use VBA to create copies (Excel and PDF) of an Excel document.

I save in the OneDrive folder (C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive) so I can access the document from every device later. I use this folder so I can save while I am connected to internet or not.

When I am connected to internet and OneDrive everything works.

When I am not connected to internet I get

> error 1004 method saveas of object _workbook failed

My macro stops but when I go to the folder the files are there.

I get the error on:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

(`Fname="C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive\YYY\ZZZ.xlsm"`)

I couldn't find anything related to this function not working on OneDrive while not connected to internet.

Comment: Are you creating a new file or are you overwriting an existing file?

Comment: I am creating a new file.

Comment: If saving into the Onedrive folder is the problem, you could always save the file(s) on your desktop and copy the file(s) to the Onedrive location using the FileSystemObject right after.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in OneDrive, I would first make sure to deactivate the AutoSave feature. I've personally had some bugs with it in the past, so it might help.

I'm not aware of this particular bug that you are experiencing, but since you are saying that the file is actually saved properly even if an error is triggered, there is a way to ignore the error and check if the file was actually saved. It would look a little like this:

```vb
Const RETRY_LIMIT = 2
Dim DoesFileExist As Boolean
dim RetryCounter as Integer

Do While RetryCounter < RETRY_LIMIT And DoesFileExist = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoesFileExist = FileExists(Fname)
    
    RetryCounter = RetryCounter + 1

Loop

If DoesFileExist = False Then
    MsgBox "Error: File couldn't be saved."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Note that I've added a retry limit of 2 to make sure that we don't go into an infinite loop.

Also make sure to add the following function in the module you are working on to make sure the code above works.

```
Function FileExists(ByVal FullFileName As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(FullFileName) <> vbNullString Then FileExists = True
End Function
```

#### Some explanations and caveats

If you have never used error handling statements such as : 
 `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo 0`, I would strongly advise you to have a look at C. Pearson's [Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) article.

To summarize, what `On Error Resume Next` does is simply ignore the error and let the code handle the error. In our case, the `DoesFileExist` does the job of making sure that the code ran without error and the if statement after the loop will make sure to stop the code if all tentative to save the file failed. This does the job, but you could also check `Err.Number` to handle different type of error as well.

Regarding `On Error GoTo 0`, to put it simply, it resets the VBA error handling to its normal state where any error will launch the usual run-time error dialog box

Comment: Thank you. I've also had issues with the autosave feature in the past. Ignoring the error will be my last solution. In the error management why are you using 'On Error Resume Next' and 'On Error GoTo 0' ? I understand that 'Resume Next' moves to the next line if there is an error but what does 'GoTo 0' do?

Comment: @Szatos I agree with you that ignoring the error should be your last resort, but in this case my answer is providing some safe guards since it checks if the file was created or not. So, it's not the same thing as blindly ignoring the error. 

Regarding `On Error GoTo 0`, to put it simply, it resets the VBA error handling to its normal state where any error will launch the usual run-time error dialog box.

Comment: Thank you for the information about error management. I didn't use the error management for this specific problem but it is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up saving the file on my desktop and then using FileSystemObject to move the file. It works fine except that if I try to open the file right away (using VBA or directly in windows explorer) I get a network error. If I wait about 1 min I don't get that error anymore. So I decided to live with it for now.

here is an example:

```
Dim FSO as Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
FSO.MoveFile("SourceFileName", "TargetFileName")
```

Thank you very much for your help